# Jetty plugin server for Maven in Netbeans 8.0.2

Tags: maven

I'm trying to run a simple example web application in Netbeans that uses Maven with the jetty plugin but the error -NetBeans: No suitable Deployment Server is defined for the project or globally.

Here is what I am working on in the code area

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>9.2.4.v20141103</version>
    <configuration>
        <httpConnector>
        <!-- make jetty listen on 127.0.0.1 for better security -->
        <!--host>127.0.0.1</host-->
        </httpConnector>
        <scanIntervalSeconds>3</scanIntervalSeconds>
        <webAppConfig>
        <!-- defaultsDescriptor>src/test/resources/jetty-maven-plugin-webdefault.xml</defaultsDescriptor -->
        </webAppConfig>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

can someone tell me what i'm missing here.

Comment: post your code here, not as a link!

Answer (score 2):

It's because you are trying to

> [Right Click] → [Run].

This will try to deploy to a normal server, for which you need to have your app configured to run with.

If you want to use the jetty-maven-plugin, you need to run the Maven goal. You can do

> [Right Click] → [Custom] → [Goals...] → [Do below] → [OK]

[image]

Clicking OK now should start the server. And because you checked the "remember as", next time you [Right Click] → [Custom], you will see the "Run Jetty" shortcut option.

Personally though I never run through Netbeans. For one, you can't ctrl+c to shutdown the server. If you have Maven installed locally, and not just in Netbeans. you can just hit the command line, from the project root and do `mvn jetty:run`

Comment: First of all thanks for that help, at the moment it looks like the server is running but the shuts down before the program is ran with this error.Jetty server exiting
Jetty server exiting.
BUILD FAILURE

Failed to execute goal org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-maven-plugin:9.2.4.v20141103:run (default-cli) on project CAServiceExample: Failure: Address already in use: bind -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug log

Comment: Looks like glass fish and Tomcat are set to port 8080, I changed tomcat but unable to edit the  port for glassfish.

Comment: You can set the `<port>` in the `<httpConnector>`

Comment: I have set the port there to 8080,8082,8079 all say the same thing address is already in use

Comment: Yeah I'm not sure. I've only had that problem a few times (when I knew there was no other server running on the port). I forgot what was causing it. I think it was just cause by starting,stopping,starting,stopping.. the server to quick. Don't think that is your problem though.

Comment: Ok so I set the sever with custom from the first post, then I set the Port from the next post and stopped all other servers. and finally I did what you said and stopped and started in and it worked perfectly now.